# Xplot and Deedle in F#

Tags: f#, deedle

I am trying to run F# to work with Deedle and google XPlot and I have the following problem: It seems that the newest version XPlot (version 1.2.2 ) needs access to the module "Deedle.FSharpFrameExtensions". However Deedle (version 1.2.4) provides  Deedle.`F# Frame extensions`.  Hence I tried to add a module with the same name :

[]
module Deedle =
     open Deedle
     type FSharpFrameExtensions = `F# Frame extensions`

But it does not seem to work. Does anyone know a Workaround ?

Comment: Do you have a link to a gist?

Comment: Here is a gist, https://gist.github.com/larjo/252ab41979459fa80a50. I get the same error and I am using the latest fslab.

Comment: No  but I tried with many scripts  to pinpoint the problem. The problem is that with new deedle the module provided by deedle is Deedle.``F# Frame extensions`` and the one required by XPlot is Deedle.FSharpFrameExtensions

Comment: Probably   module  XPlot.GoogleCharts.Deedle needs update. I tried some older versions of fslab. The previous to the current one does not work either, so I tried v FsLab.0.2.7 and it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the FSLab package from nuget? That is about all you need/want in a package, and as such the versioning all over is (should be?) ok.

Check out http://fslab.org/ and especially http://fslab.org/download/ for different download/usage options.

Comment: I tried th FSlab package as per your suggestion but is not ok. Version are the same with what I used, and the problem persists